# How to import an adjacency array from a file in .txt format with edge notation (v, w)?

Tags: r, igraph, adjacency-matrix, edges

How to import an adjacency array from a file in .txt format with edge notation (v, w) in RStudio?

The contents of the .txt file are as follows:

```
5vertices,não dirigido
0,1
1,2
1,3
2,3
3,4
4,0
Reinforcement that this is the notation of vertices in the format (v, w).
vertices: 0 to 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear nor reproducible. For example, I don't know what you mean by an "adjacency array".

That aside, *assuming* you have a text file (which I call `sample.txt` here) with the following content

```
5vertices,não dirigido
0,1
1,2
1,3
2,3
3,4
4,0
Reinforcement that this is the notation of vertices in the format (v, w).
vertices: 0 to 4
```

you can use `readLines` to read the file line-by-line, extract the edge list and create an `igraph` object:

```
ln <- readLines("sample.txt")

# Store as matrix with from/to indices
vtx <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(ln[grep("\\d+,\\d+", ln)], ","))

# Convert indices to integer and convert to igraph
library(igraph)
ig <- graph_from_data_frame(apply(vtx, 2, as.integer))

plot(ig)
```

[image]

Comment: very good!!
Thank you!! that's exactly what I was asking. Now, I could not identify how to make the graph not directed, how would it be?
once, thank you

Comment: Get! just add the "directed = False" argument in the "graph_form_data_frame" function: ig <- graph_from_data_frame (apply (vtx, directed = FALSE, 2, as.integer), directed = FALSE.

Comment: @Tiago If this answers your question please close the question by setting the green checkmark next to the answer. That way you help keeping SO tidy and make it easier for future SO users to identify relevant questions.